# How can I Avoid Nested For-loop for choosing a combination?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, search, combinations

For instance, there are **M attributes** a_1, ..., a_M **to choose** and **each attribute has N choices**.
The problem is to **search whole combinations of N ^ M choices.**
Using nested for-loop, the pseudo-code is like below.

```
# length of a_1, ..., a_M is N for each.
for c_1 in a_1:
  for c_2 in a_2:
    ...
      for c_M in a_M:
         evaluate(c_1, c_2, ..., c_M)
```

However, this extreme nested for-loop looks very poor and I don't want to write for-statement M times.
Also, if we don't know the number of attributes to consider, we cannot even use this code.
Are there any more simple and elegant ways doing as above?

Comment: Attributes `a_1, ..., a_M` should be stored in some collection like array or list. In this case you need only two loops

Comment: Thanks to comment, but this problem is not about just choosing one of a_1 and see it. Choosing (x for a_1, y for a_2, ..., z for a _M) <=> (x, y, ..., z) is one selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your problem refers to cartesian product. Note that result size (number of combinations) is `L1*L2*L3..*LM` where `Li` is number of choises for `ai`

You can implement it using recursion or use appropriate library if available

Python example:

```
import itertools
l = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], [False, True]]
print([list(a) for a in itertools.product(*l)])

>>> [['a', 1, False], ['a', 1, True], ['a', 2, False], ['a', 2, True], 
     ['a', 3, False], ['a', 3, True], ['b', 1, False], ['b', 1, True], 
     ['b', 2, False], ['b', 2, True], ['b', 3, False], ['b', 3, True]]
```

Example of recursive and iterative implementations:

```
def product_rec(a, fromindex, res):
    if fromindex == len(a):
        print(res)
        return
    for x in a[fromindex]:
        product_rec(a, fromindex+1, res+[x])

def product_iter(a):
    NN = 1
    for x in a:
        NN *=  len(x)  #number of combinations
    b = [[0]*len(a) for i in range(NN)]
    N = NN
    M = 1
    for k in range(len(a)):  
        N //=  len(a[k])
        c = 0
        for l in range(M):
            for i in range(len(a[k])):
                for j in range(N):
                    b[c][k] = a[k][i]
                    c += 1
        M *= len(a[k])
    print(b)

l = [['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3], [False, True]]

product_rec(l, 0, [])
product_iter(l)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. I'm sorry that there had been some mistakes. I confused you by writing M * N choices. Actually, N ^ M choices here.

Comment: If you've time, could you please explain how can I implement this wok by recursion? DFS came across my mind, but I couldn't devise concrete code..

Comment: I added both recursive and iterative implementations. I'm not very experienced in Python, so code is just to demonstrate approaches.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness!